# How to generate google autocomplete address api dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, autocomplete

I need to generate n number address grabber and get the formatted output in json, which I can do via ajax on button click. But I am not getting how can I use google api to generate autocomplete dynamically and get the things separately.

I need to show exactly the same type of design which is attached in this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/6BcUD/

```
initialize();

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      { types: ['geocode'] });
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
}

function fillInAddress() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
          position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      autocomplete.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation,
          geolocation));
    });
  }
}
```

Currently I have added 3 forms, but I need to add it via a "Add form" button, which I think I can do by using jquery append. But how to make it work in google autocomplete?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript code must be more "generic" and not based on DOM elements ids if you want to re-use it to manage multiple forms.

The global var containing the autocomplete instance is neitheir a good idea.

I edited your jsFiddle to suggest you a jQuery based solution (you put jQuery tag so i assume i can rely on):

- i defined a div `#addressForms` where forms will be appended after cliking on `#addForm` button
- i've wrapped your form makup in an hidden div `#template`. Each time you click on `#addForm`, the template content will be copied, initialized with autocomplete and appended to `#addressForms`
- as DOM elements ids must be unique, i removed your form elements ids and use them as css classes
- i also removed your global var `componentForm` and added data (`data-type`) on each field element

Have a look in the <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6BcUD/3/)</kbd> if it feet your needs.

**EDIT:**

I created this <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7N3NG/2/)</kbd> accordingly to your comments. It's not finished yet but it can help.

Comment: I edited the jsFiddle to add a `for` loop in `#addForm` click function. I also replace css class with `data-component` attribute to build data to send in ajax call. Have a look in the `#sendData` click function to perform your ajax call. You need to modify it to specify your url and maybe to modify data format (data are written behind the form to illustrate what is generated). And don't forget to accept an answer in SO!

Comment: Ok in fact when you click on 'Order a delivery', you need the modal to open with 'Order #1' containing the form with all fields and autocomplete initialized. And then clicking on 'Add form' will add a 'Order #2' with a second form initialized right ? You need to adapt the script if so. Confirm me that's what you want to do, i will help you tonight or tomorow. Then you will have to continue by yourself, i can't do all your work :D